# How to implement path resolving when template was already passed to Freemerker for rendering?

Tags: struts2, freemarker

I'm working on issue [WW-4145](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4145?focusedCommentId=13716347&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-13716347) in Apache Struts 2 to allow extending Struts tags written with FreeMarker. The problem is how to resolve path after `MultiTemplateLoader` already did resolve the path. Or in other words, if the proposed solution will be efficient?

```
<#macro includeThemeTemplate templateName>
  <#list parameters.themeHierarchy as theme>
    <#attempt>
      <#include "/${parameters.templateDir}/${theme}/${templateName}" />
      <#break/>
    <#recover>
    </#attempt>
  </#list>
  <#-- Cause an exception intentionally which will have the top most theme -->
  <#include "/${parameters.templateDir}/${parameters.themeHierarchy[0]}/${templateName}" />
</#macro>
```

and usage in tag:

```
<@includeThemeTemplate "controlheader.ftl"/>
<#include "/${parameters.templateDir}/simple/checkboxlist.ftl" />
<@includeThemeTemplate "controlfooter.ftl"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with it as FreeMarker caches failed template lookups (means this should not generate too much I/O, providing the update-delay isn't too small). However, for framework-level stuff you might consider using Java instead, as it's faster and often more maintainable. The Java equivalent of `#include` is `freemarker.core.Environment.include`. To get the `Environment` object you can use `Environment.getCurrentEnvironment()` (or if you are using a `TemplateDirectiveModel`, that will get it as parameter).